# Not able to find first() and follow() for non LR grammer

Tags: parsing, context-free-grammar, ll-grammar, left-recursion

I have removed left recursion from the given grammar. But, now I have to find out first and follow to create a parse table.

Original : 
   `S -> aSb | bSa | SS | epsilon`

New: After removing left recursion : 
       `S -> aSbSS' | bSaSS' | S'` and 
        `S'-> SS' | epsilon`

I am trying to do first(S)= {a, b} and first(S')
But first(S) is first (SS'). Now this is becoming recursive. How do I find the first and follow for the non terminals S and S' ?

Comment: This [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29197332/how-to-find-first-and-follow-sets-of-a-recursive-grammar) solves only for FOLLOW. Should I make  the grammer as immediate left recursive and solve for FIRST? Because, I just removed left recursion.

Comment: Now the set in FIRST and FOLLOW are same. It will create 2 entries in the parse table. So, even if I remove Left recursion, the table still contains 2 productions for a single non terminal. Is this right?

Comment: If S is still recursive, you haven't actually removed left recursion. You've only removed direct left recursion. Also, removing left recursion doesn't remove ambiguity. Ambiguous grammars produce parsing tables with conflicts.

Comment: Anyway, you can solve for FIRST sets in the same way as you do for FOLLOW sets, even for left-recursive grammars. But the left-recursive grammar has no LL parser, regardless of whether the direction is direct or not.

Comment: Thanks for the response @rici. 
I have removed the left recursion as given : `S -> aSbSS' | bSaSS' | S' and  S'-> SS' | epsilon`. So, do you mean to say even after removing left recursion, the parsing table can contain multiple entries?

Comment: Yes, that is correct. There are many grammars which are not left recursive, which still cannot be parsed with an LL(k) automaton.

Comment: I just tried to construct a parse tree for a string using the non left recursive grammar which I did and I could construct another tree for the same string. So, this means it is ambiguous right? And, yes, it has multiple entries in the table. So, this is not LL(1). 

Thank you so much for the response.